# workbench cvs update set field to null

Tags: update, workbench

In Workbench I am query Account and I want to set ParentId to null (there are some bad id's and I want to clear them). However when I clear out the cvs file and update using workbench the values are not cleared, when I rerun the Query. I am using excel to clear the values with a Delete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a setting in work bench that you need to check called 'Insert Null Values'.  This should allow you to do updates with null values.

Comment: Workbench->Settings: Check Insert Null Values, Apply Settings. Enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

And the value for the CSV column should be `{empty}`, don't put NULL, it won't work.

Comment: Nope. Blank string works though, null and {empty} do not